# css bold first line in div

Tags: css

I have a bunch of divs like the following on one page. Is there a way in css to bold just the first line (before the `<br/>`)? So, in this instance, I would want Customer in bold.

```
<div>
Customer
<br/>
John Doe
</div>
```

Comment: Searching the web for “css first line” will give you [this page](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/), which tells you exactly how to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any effort or research

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for the ::first-line pseudo-element.

So basically you'd do:

```
div::first-line{
 font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use the [:first-line pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line):

```css
div::first-line {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
Customer
<br/>
John Doe
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pseudo-element [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)

```css
div::first-line {
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<div>
Customer
<br/>
John Doe
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [::first-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-line) selector. According to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link4), it is widely supported. MDN [provides more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

Answer (score 0):

I am not too good at css but hope this **pseudo-element** doucmentation help more to lean about pseudo selectors.
and Thanks to @MKN Web Solutions for great and quick answer.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line